# is it possible to install magento on iis server?

Tags: magento-1.9, server-setup, windows

we are trying to migrate an existing Magento website to our server is it possible to **install Magento on windows IIS web server**?

Comment: Yous should review the following http://tarunjadav.blogspot.com/2013/09/magento-run-on-iis-and-installation.html

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Magento System Requirements](http://magento.com/resources/system-requirements) IIS is not supported out of the box by Magento:

> Operating System : Linux x86-64
>
> Web Server:
>
> - Apache 2.x
> - Nginx 1.7.x

However, it seems like some people achieved to install Magento on IIS and even better, they documented how to do it. You can find a detailed guide here: http://tarunjadav.blogspot.fr/2013/09/magento-run-on-iis-and-installation.html

Answer (score 1):

I made a step-by-step instructions for Deploying Magento on IIS here:

http://www.drupalonwindows.com/en/blog/installing-magento-windows-and-iis

It uses integrator build and deployment strategies, and has updated web.config files and configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

We have a production environment running for sometime on IIS and all dev work takes place on IIS. There were some quirks and difficulties getting it set up, like the installer not thinking it had finished when it had, but actually it has generally been very easy. The performance is also very promising too.